# Тестирование тестов в Docker image

Tags: java, docker

Поставлена задача перевести автоматические тесты QA в Docker. Идея в вледующем:
1) Создать Docker image под Java 8, с браузерами Chrome , FireFox. 
1.1. Как это сделать правельно?
1.2. В настоящее время использую docker-compose который берет эти браузеры из docker-hub, связывает их с hum и утсанавливает порты. Как это сделать в новой docker image? Мы используем Гугл Клауд а он только может испльзовать dokcer file, docker-compose он не признает

2) Также нужно сделать так чтобы исходный код с тестами при каждом вызове этой image шел на Гитхаю репозиторий и брал от туда последний кон с мастера

3) Ну и конечно чтобы можно было это вызывать через команду mvn test -P ci -Durl "https...(это тестировачная environment)".

Провел день с этим, начальник спрашивает, а у меня ничего нет вообще, я в этом не понимаю, а специального человека devops у нас нет. Если можно опишите подробные шаги

Спасибо

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Отличный у вас начальник, что можно сказать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Поставлена задача перевести автоматические тесты QA в Docker.

Непростая, но **интересная задача**.

> 2) Также нужно сделать так чтобы исходный код с тестами при каждом вызове этой image шел на Гитхаю репозиторий и брал от туда последний кон с мастера

**Не надо так.**

**Проводим инвенторизацию:**

- Github repo + Github Actions (CI)
- Google Cloud

В github repo добавляем `workflow` для тестирования ([Пример](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-swarm-mode/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml)).

**CI / CD pipeline:**

- **Реальность ...**
- Разработчик пушит в repo - запускает build образа приложения (on-push, on-merge)
- Линты / unit тестирование / etc
- Заливаем образ приложения на Google Cloud (нужный environment)
- **TODO: Запускаем интеграционные тесты**
- Деплой на продакшен

> Провел день с этим, начальник спрашивает, а у меня ничего нет вообще, я в этом не понимаю, а специального человека devops у нас нет. Если можно опишите подробные шаги

Логично, что с этим проблема, так как CI / CD - нету или про него не знаете.

**Как поступить**:

- Узнать про **CI / CD** или **начать** его **делать пошагово**
- **Быть готовым** к тому, что **просрочите срок и не раз**
- **После запуска CI**, обязательно **появятся проблемы** с **`workflow`**
- Делать **маленькие образы** (alpine based), **кешировать**, **ускорять pipeline**

**Tips & Tricks**:

- build / unit / lint можно совместить с **docker multi-stage build**